Keycloak 24.03 Remove User's Federation Link through required action
I have a keycloak server with Users Imported from Ldap and synced to it, I want to remove the federation link for those users. I already took care of updating the users directly via keycloak API. However, the authentication is handled by ldap right now so I can't just unlink them if they don't have keycloak credentials.
What I'd like to do is create a required action something like the existing update password but handling the removal of federation link. I search an exemple but couldn't find one.
public void processAction(RequiredActionContext context) {
    EventBuilder event = context.getEvent();
    AuthenticationSessionModel authSession = context.getAuthenticationSession();
    UserModel user = context.getUser();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
    event.event(EventType.UPDATE_PASSWORD);
    String passwordNew = formData.getFirst("password-new");
    String passwordConfirm = formData.getFirst("password-confirm");

    EventBuilder errorEvent = event.clone().event(EventType.UPDATE_PASSWORD_ERROR)
            .client(authSession.getClient())
            .user(authSession.getAuthenticatedUser());        

    if ("on".equals(formData.getFirst("logout-sessions"))) {
        AuthenticatorUtil.logoutOtherSessions(context);
    }

    try {
        user.credentialManager().updateCredential(UserCredentialModel.password(passwordNew, false));
        //Remove User Federation Link here (?)
        context.success();
    } catch (ModelException me) {
    // handling errors

